# How to model ownership of a resource (e.g. credit card)

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm trying to figure out how to model ownership of a resource. An example can be a credit card. In a scenario a credit card can be owned by a `company`, a `business` or a `business_admin` which is used to pay for a service that belongs to a `business`.

What I came up with is a table `business_payment` that references `company_payment_method`, `business_payment_method`, `business_admin_payment_method` as well as the `business` that gets the payment method assigned. They are all nullable which requires a trigger to check if the insert is valid - exactly *one* ID must be not null before insert:

```
CREATE TABLE business_payment (

    business_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk__business_payment__business
        FOREIGN KEY (business_id)
        REFERENCES business(id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE,

    company_payment_method_id BIGINT,

    CONSTRAINT fk__business_payment__company_payment_method
        FOREIGN KEY (company_payment_method_id)
        REFERENCES company_payment_method(id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE,

    business_payment_method_id BIGINT,

    CONSTRAINT fk__business_payment__business_payment_method
        FOREIGN KEY (business_payment_method_id)
        REFERENCES business_payment_method(id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE,

    business_admin_payment_method_id BIGINT,

    CONSTRAINT fk__business_payment__business_admin_payment_method
        FOREIGN KEY (business_admin_payment_method_id)
        REFERENCES business_admin_payment_method(id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

---

**Pro:**

The advantage I see here is that if any of the credit cards are deleted e.g.

```
DELETE FROM company_credit_card WHERE id = @companyCreditCardId;
```

also the `business_payment_method` will get deleted. On the application layer nobody has to take care of the cleaning this up.

**Con:**

On the other hand I now have a table which has `NULL` values and if Ever there was a new entity `x_credit_card` I'd have to add this column to this table as well as make sure the trigger does its job correctly.

---

So this is the solution I was thinking about but I'm not sure if this is very elegant - especially because I'm creating an M*N matrix with (M*N - M) `NULL` entries.

Can I do better than this setup?

Below is the complete code if you want to check it out. Unfortunately I can't make it run on SQLFiddle because of this `DELIMITER` thing.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS company_business;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS company_employee;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS payment_method;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS business_payment;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS business_admin_payment_method;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS company_payment_method;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS business_payment_method;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS company;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS business_admin;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS business;

CREATE TABLE company (      
    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE business_admin (       
    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE business (
    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE company_employee (

    company_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk__company_employee__company 
        FOREIGN KEY (company_id)
        REFERENCES company(id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE,

    business_admin_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk_company_employee__business_admin
        FOREIGN KEY (business_admin_id)
        REFERENCES business_admin(id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE,

    PRIMARY KEY (company_id, business_admin_id)

);

CREATE TABLE company_business (

    company_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk__company_business__company
        FOREIGN KEY (company_id)
        REFERENCES company(id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE,

    business_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk__company_business__business
        FOREIGN KEY (business_id)
        REFERENCES business(id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE,

    PRIMARY KEY (company_id, business_id)

);

SET @businessAdminId1 = 1;
INSERT INTO business_admin(id) VALUES (@businessAdminId1);

SET @companyId1 = 1;
INSERT INTO company(id) VALUES (@companyId1);
INSERT INTO company_employee(company_id, business_admin_id) VALUES (@companyId1,@businessAdminId1);

SET @businessId1 = 1;
INSERT INTO business VALUES (@businessId1);
INSERT INTO company_business VALUES(@companyId1, @businessId1);

CREATE TABLE company_payment_method (

    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,

    company_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk__company_payment_method__company
        FOREIGN KEY (company_id)
        REFERENCES company(id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE,

    payment_method_token VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE business_payment_method (

    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,

    business_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk__business_payment_method__business
        FOREIGN KEY (business_id)
        REFERENCES business(id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE,

    payment_method_token VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE business_admin_payment_method (

    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,

    business_admin_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk__business_admin_payment_method__business_admin
        FOREIGN KEY (business_admin_id)
        REFERENCES business_admin(id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE,

    payment_method_token VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE business_payment (

    business_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk__business_payment__business
        FOREIGN KEY (business_id)
        REFERENCES business(id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE,

    company_payment_method_id BIGINT,

    CONSTRAINT fk__business_payment__company_payment_method
        FOREIGN KEY (company_payment_method_id)
        REFERENCES company_payment_method(id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE,

    business_payment_method_id BIGINT,

    CONSTRAINT fk__business_payment__business_payment_method
        FOREIGN KEY (business_payment_method_id)
        REFERENCES business_payment_method(id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE,

    business_admin_payment_method_id BIGINT,

    CONSTRAINT fk__business_payment__business_admin_payment_method
        FOREIGN KEY (business_admin_payment_method_id)
        REFERENCES business_admin_payment_method(id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
);

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_business_payment_method BEFORE INSERT ON business_payment
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE notNullForeignKeyFound BOOLEAN;
    DECLARE errorMessage VARCHAR(100);

    SET errorMessage = 'Exact one foreign key must be not null!';   
    SET notNullForeignKeyFound = FALSE;

    -- Company credit card ID

    IF NEW.company_payment_method_id IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET notNullForeignKeyFound = TRUE;
    END IF;

    -- Business credit card ID

    IF NEW.business_payment_method_id IS NOT NULL THEN
        IF notNullForeignKeyFound IS TRUE THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = errorMessage;
        END IF;
        SET notNullForeignKeyFound = TRUE;
    END IF;

    -- Business admin credit card ID

    IF NEW.business_admin_payment_method_id IS NOT NULL THEN
        IF notNullForeignKeyFound IS TRUE THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = errorMessage;
        END IF;
        SET notNullForeignKeyFound = TRUE;
    END IF;

    -- Check if at least one ID is not null

    IF notNullForeignKeyFound IS FALSE THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = errorMessage;
    END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;

SET @companyCreditCardId1 = 1;
INSERT INTO company_payment_method (id, company_id, payment_method_token) VALUES (@companyCreditCardId1, @companyId1, 'wergef');

SET @businessCreditCardId1 = 1;
INSERT INTO business_payment_method (id, business_id, payment_method_token) VALUES (@businessCreditCardId1, @businessId1, 'asjio');

--
-- Here comes the actual action ..
-- 

-- Succeeds
INSERT INTO business_payment (business_id, business_payment_method_id) VALUES (@businessId1, @companyCreditCardId1);

-- Fails
-- INSERT INTO business_payment (business_id, company_payment_method_id, business_payment_method_id) VALUES (@businessId1, @companyCreditCardId1, @businessCreditCardId1);


-- The following will delete:
--   + business_payment_method.payment_method_id = 1
--   + busuiness_payment_method.payment_method_id = 1

DELETE FROM business_payment_method WHERE id = @companyCreditCardId1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be for you to have a business_entity table with an entity_type(business, employee, admin, etc.).   Payment could have a single Foreign Key back to entity.  You would then have a detail table for each entity type that would have the detail information for that particular type of entity.

`business_entity--1----M--business_payment
 |    |--1-----1--employee
 |--1-------1--admin`

Comment: A supertype entity set would be my preference as well. This is easy enough to do before the database is implemented, but messy afterwards if the subtypes have overlapping or incompatible keys. In that case we have to handle the supertype as a new entity set in a 1:1 relationship with the subtypes.

Comment: Subtypes should never have overlapping or incompatible keys. This would indicate a serious flaw in the design.